# Rendering a partial with a Stripe button — undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render a Stripe button in registrations#edit but the instance variable stripe_btn_data is returning nil. I’m not sure what’s going on:

Here's the partial call in *registrations/edit.html.erb* (Devise)

`<%= render partial: 'charges/premium_button', locals: { stripe_btn_data: @stripe_btn_data } %>`

The content of the partial in *charges/_premium_button.html.erb*

```
<% if ! stripe_btn_data.nil? %>
    <p><code>stripe_btn_data</code> is nil</p>
<% else %>
   <%= form_tag charges_path do %>
      <h5>Upgrade your account!</h5>
      <script class='stripe-button'
          src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
          data-key="<%= stripe_btn_data[:key] %>"
          data-amount=<%= stripe_btn_data[:amount] %>
          data-description="<%= stripe_btn_data[:description] %>" >
      </script>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And finally my `ChargesController`

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  class Amount
    def self.default
      @amount = 10_00
    end
  end

  def new
    @stripe_btn_data = {
        key: "#{ Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] }",
        description: "Premium Membership - #{current_user.username}",
        amount: Amount.default
    }
  end

  def create
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        email: current_user.email,
        card: params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        customer: customer.id, # Note -- this is NOT the user_id in your app
        amount: Amount.default,
        description: "Premium Membership - #{current_user.email}",
        currency: 'usd'
    )

    flash[:notice] = "Thanks for all the money, #{current_user.email}! Feel free to pay me again."
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end

end
```

[Here's the error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3a8r.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

### Solution

I created a `RegistrationsController` as I had to override Devise's default and added the `edit` action.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def edit
    @amount = 10_00

    @stripe_btn_data = {
        key: "#{ Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] }",
        description: "Premium Membership - #{current_user.username}",
        amount: @amount
    }
  end
end
```

Finally I edited my *routes.rb* file to tell Devise to use the new `RegistrationsController`

`devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}`

Comment: As @djaszczurowski said, you should paste RegistrationsController#edit. Do you have a `@stripe_btn_data` there?

Comment: No, `@stripe_btn_data` is defined in the `new` action of `ChargesController`. I don't have a `RegistrationsController`. The `edit.html.erb` view is from Devise.

Comment: You're calling the partial from your `registrations/edit.html.erb`, which is a view from `RegistrationsController`, the `new` action in `ChargesController` isn't called anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pasted `ChargesController`, but you should paste `RegistrationsController` as from its `edit` method partial is rendered.

Comment: Thank you! I created a RegistrationsController and moved the definition of `@stripe_btn_data` to an `edit` action and worked fine. I'm still learning Rails. Thanks for the hints.